# TSQL create an average count for weeks over multiple years

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create an average count per week over multiple years. For example if I have:

```
select w.weekno, isNULL(AVG(quantity),0) as 'mcount'
from weeks w
left join sampledates sd ON w.weekNo = datepart(wk,sd.sampledate)
inner join sampledate_species_location ssdl ON sd.sampledateid = ssdl.sampledateid
inner join locations l ON ssdl.locationid = l.locationid 
inner join species s ON ssdl.speciesid = s.speciesid 
where year(sd.sampledate) = datepart(yy,getDate())
and l.locationid = 8 
and l.generalarea = 'Western'
group by w.weekno
order by w.weekno
```

What I need for my results would look something like:

```
WEEK     MCOUNT
17       0
18       6
19       7
20       8
21       9
22       5
23       0
24       8
```

I created a table called weeks with weeks 17-41 in it as the weekNo hoping that left joining it to the results would include the week numbers where I have no quantity, but that is not working. I also have to do this same query but for all previous years, which I am not certain how I would average multiple years, by week in this same format.

Comment: CROSS APPLY here is the only thing that well get you out of this pickle. Stepping out of the office for now. Will try and get back to this when I get home. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx
edit: Simply put, cross apply to a select that filters down every year individually - even down to the week if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `where` clause and the `inner join`s.  You need to continue the `left outer join`s for all tables.  Then, the `where` conditions need to be in the `on` clause (otherwise the `left joins` are turned into `inner join`s):

```
select w.weekno, isNULL(AVG(quantity),0) as 'mcount'
from weeks w left join
     sampledates sd
     ON w.weekNo = datepart(wk, sd.sampledate) and
        year(sd.sampledate) = datepart(yy, getDate()) left join
     sampledate_species_location ssdl
     ON sd.sampledateid = ssdl.sampledateid left join
     locations l
     ON ssdl.locationid = l.locationid and
        l.locationid = 8 and
        l.generalarea = 'Western' left join
     species s
     ON ssdl.speciesid = s.speciesid 
group by w.weekno
order by w.weekno;
```

Comment: I previously tried this and was using SUM instead of AVG. What I get back was a massive quantity because it is somehow ignoring the conditions for date and location. Using AVG gives incorrect quantities as well.

Comment: I just realized that if I also included sd.sampledateid = ssdl.sampledateid AND l.locationid = 8 then it would remove the extra rows with unrelated quantities.